# M 1.9.0.1 - path hints showing in order email

Tags: magento-1.9, email, template-hints

Believe it or not but my customer forwarded an order-email where the template path hints of the single blocks are showing.

```
Nothing changed in config

Path hints disabled

Developer client IP set
```

It seems like it was only for this specific email. No other Emails affected.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

EDIT: To make it clear:
It was an order email sent for an order created manually in admin panel which has different store view and therefore different settings where "display path hints" was true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How this possibly could happen:

- By default, you can only set template path hints per website or per store view. But if the configuration value is set directly in the database on a global level, maybe to use them in the admin area, emails sent from admin or cron will show the template hints too at this time.
- It could have been an issue with block cache after you had enabled path hints and disabled them again, but this would only affect cachable blocks and most if not all blocks in the order email are not cached.

Answer (score 0):

When Order placed at that time Template Path Hints should be Active from admin, So it is displayed in email.