# Template path hints are displayed in order emails

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

I just found that when we had the template path hints activated, the path hints actually were displayed in the email notifications for orders and shipments that were emailed to customers. Does anyone know how to disable this from appearing in the emails?

Comment: This resource can help you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98115/m-1-9-0-1-path-hints-showing-in-order-email

Answer (score 1):

Final decision whether to display template path hints logic can be found here:

Mage_Core_Block_Template::getShowTemplateHints()

You have two options:

1) rewrite this block and override this method adding your custom logic (don't display template hints if the block is related to email content) which seems to be better than option no. 2

or

2) right before sending an email try to update you database but cache flushing may be needed in this scenario, so try to do something like this:
update core_config_data set value=0 where path ='dev/debug/template_hints';
update core_config_data set value=0 where path = 'dev/debug/template_hints_blocks';
of course add your store id to the condition and then flush caches for blocks and layouts only.

Comment: I like option 1). I will look into the implementation.